# Invalid geometry - lines

Tags: qgis, buffer, clip

In QGIS I'm attempting to create a buffer zone around a number of connected lines, then use the buffer layer to clip another layer. The lines features were provided as a shape file, and buffering works fine. However when I try to clip with the buffered layer I get an error stating 'invalid geometry'. Upon closer inspection, there is a line not connected to the others (see image), which appears to be the source of the error. How do I connect this line to the other? I've experimented with edit features (extend, reshape etc.) but can't seem to find the function I require to link them.[image]

Comment: This is not an invalid geometry. Invalid geometries are e.g. self intersecting geometries, or duplicate nodes.

Comment: When I dissolve buffer the lines into a new layer, then try to clip another layer with this buffered layer I get this message: Feature (36) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.
Execution failed after 0.06 seconds

Comment: Use Fix Geometries tool to fix them

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fix geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisfixgeometries) to fix them:

> Attempts to create a valid representation of a given invalid geometry
> without losing any of the input vertices. Already valid geometries are
> returned without further intervention. Always outputs multi-geometry
> layer.